# Make doesn't like $(addprefix a,b)

Tags: makefile, build

Make is giving me the error:

```
make/sources.make:16: *** missing separator.  Stop.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

The code that is generating this error is:

```
$(addprefix a,b)
```

I've checked for spaces, but I didn't find anything.
If I comment it out, no errors are given. I've narrowed it down to this one line, and I can't figure it out. 'a' and 'b' can be replaced with anything, and it still won't work. However, if you remove all arguments to it, like this `$(addprefix ,)` then no errors are given.

What is going on here?

Full code of makefile that contains the error:

```
# sources.make - source files

# path of source files
SOURCEPATH=src

# build list of source files
# categorize source files

SOURCE_MAIN=main.c

# add categories to SOURCES as needed
SOURCES+=$(SOURCE_MAIN)

# add the SOURCEPATH to each source file
#$(addprefix $(SOURCEPATH),$(SOURCES)) <------ This is the true error code
$(addprefix a,b)

# extra files to remove
TRASHFILES = stdout.txt stderr.txt

# extra directories to remove
TRASHDIRS = junkdir

# build target
TARGET = $(PROG)$(EXT)

# generate object files
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

# generate dependency files
DEPENDS = $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SOURCES))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offending line is interpreted as a rule, not a directive. It should instead read:

```
SOURCES := $(addprefix $(SOURCEPATH)/,$(SOURCES))
```